async function as hashmap value type
I want to store some aysnc operations in a hashmap. Then get a async operation list  based on the user input string list.
By search the site,I found this question
How can I put an async function into a map in Rust?
The difference is that I want to use the stored operation hashmap  across diffrent tokio thread.
So I rewrite with once_cell + RwLock.
Full example
static MAPS: Lazy<Arc<RwLock<HashMap<&'static str, CalcFn>>>> = Lazy::new(|| {
    let map = Arc::new(RwLock::new(HashMap::new()));
    let mut map_lock = map.write().unwrap();
    map_lock.insert(
        "add",
        Box::new(
            move |a: i32, b: i32| -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = BoxedResult<i32>>>> {
                Box::pin(add(a, b))
            },
        ) as CalcFn,
    );
    map_lock.insert(
        "sub",
        Box::new(
            move |a: i32, b: i32| -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = BoxedResult<i32>>>> {
                Box::pin(sub(a, b))
            },
        ) as CalcFn,
    );
    map.clone()
});

The lazy initialization seems boring and takes a lot of lines in code beacause I may have 20+  async operations.
Could someone kindly offer some comments to write this example in a "cleaner" way?

If the verbosity of the repetition is the problem, surely you can compose a function that does it for you, no?

yes.I know function  or macro rule would take help.  In fact,  I'm looking for if there is another way or data structure also achive the same goal.

The first thing to do is move as much as possible from the insert operation into another function.
fn insert_async_fn<K, F, Fut>(map: &mut HashMap<K, CalcFn>, name: K, f: F)
where
    K: Eq + Hash,
    F: Fn(i32, i32) -> Fut + Send + Sync + 'static,
    Fut: Future<Output = BoxedResult<i32>> + Send + 'static,
{
    map.insert(name, Box::new(move |a, b| Box::pin(f(a, b))));
}

// Used like this
insert_async_fn(&mut map, "add", add);
insert_async_fn(&mut map, "sub", sub);

You don't need to use clone at the end. All you need to do is drop the lock before returning.
drop(map_lock);
map

You don't need the Arc. Arc can be used to ensure a value stays alive across multiple threads, but static already ensures that.
In the code you posted, you also don't need RwLock, but it might be necessary if you are modifying the map after construction.
If you're using the latest stable version of Rust, you can use LazyLock from the standard library. It works the same as the one from once_cell.
You usually don't need errors to be Sync, but you do often need futures to be Send, so that they can be spawned on multithreaded runtimes.
That leaves us with this:
static MAPS: LazyLock<RwLock<HashMap<&'static str, CalcFn>>> = LazyLock::new(|| {
    let mut map = HashMap::new();

    insert_async_fn(&mut map, "add", add);
    insert_async_fn(&mut map, "sub", sub);

    RwLock::new(map)
});

fn insert_async_fn<K, F, Fut>(map: &mut HashMap<K, CalcFn>, name: K, f: F)
where
    K: Eq + Hash,
    F: Fn(i32, i32) -> Fut + Send + Sync + 'static,
    Fut: Future<Output = BoxedResult<i32>> + Send + 'static,
{
    map.insert(name, Box::new(move |a, b| Box::pin(f(a, b))));
}

Rust playground

I got another problem when using tokio::spawn  based on your example.
Rust playground
I've tried with tokio::sync::Mutex and Arc to solve this compile error. But failed.
Could you please kindly give me a hand? @drewtato

@zhaokaixie you need to drop the lock before awaiting the future. You could avoid binding the lock to a variable and then awaiting just the future https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=a7d165e5ce83746cf5192818e01d679c but this is a bit verbose, so it might be worth making them clonable https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=8b371427b72b37bf74993f22a0c013b9
